# Can I retrieve wso2 store apis by filtering with name of api using rest apis

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

There is a rest api to retrieve all published apis in wso2 store. But I didn't find a rest api to filter out store apis by name, provider or version. Is there a rest api for my requirement or can I customize find all api?

Comment: Find a way to filter using                                   
/api/am/store/v0.10/apis?query=name:<api-name>                                                                        Is this a recommended??

Comment: /api/am/store/v0.10/apis?query=name:<api-name>  Can I provide more than one query param for this api

Comment: yes. you can use above to filter APIs by name, if you want to filter by provider use,  /api/am/store/v0.10/apis?query=provider:<provider_name> and to filter by version use  /api/am/store/v0.10/apis?query=version:<api-version>. You can find the supported list of query prefixes (in the latest APIM version 3.0.0) here https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/Learn/ConsumeAPI/DiscoverAPIs/search/

Comment: And yes, you can provide more than one query param for the API, for example if you want to filter APIs having the name *like* PizzaShack and the version as 1.0 the query string would be 'name:PizzaShack version:1.0', You have to url encode this section before using, ex : /api/am/store/v0.10/apis?query=name%3APizzaShack%20version%3A1.0

Comment: I tested for more than one query param as  /api/am/store/v0.10/apis?query=name%3AAp1-ms6-Ap1-ms6%20provider%3Aadmin But it gives an error message. {
    "description": "Provided query parameter 'name:Ap1-ms6-Ap1-ms6 provider:admin' is invalid",
    "error": [],
    "code": 400,
    "moreInfo": "",
    "message": "Bad Request"
}

Comment: seems you are using APIM 2.0.0. multiple term search is not supported in 2.0.0 rest API. But it is supported in newer versions.

Comment: However you can use the jaggery API instead. Please refer Login and Search APIs section in https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Store+APIs#StoreAPIs-SearchAPIs. A sample curl would be like curl -X POST -b cookies "http://localhost:9763/store/site/blocks/search/api-search/ajax/search.jag" -d "action=searchAPIs&query=name%3AAp1-ms6-Ap1-ms6%20provider%3Aadmin&start=0&end=3"